# matplotlib - What am I doing wrong here?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

Recently I started learning Matplotlib. I wrote one of my code and saw that the output is weird. This is my code and below that the output of this code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

plt.style.use('seaborn')    
data = pd.read_csv('C:/py/matplotlib/08-TimeSeries/data.csv')
   
price_date = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'])
data.sort_values('Date', inplace=True)    
price_close = data['Close']

plt.plot_date(price_date, price_close, linestyle='solid')    
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

this is the entire code and the output of the above code looks like this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong in there, I doubt `price_date = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'])` this is why I am getting this error, but there could be other reasons. Can you please help with this?

Comment: What is the error?  If the graph should look different, *what* should it look like?

Comment: I knew it is not expected, because no one can read this graph. It doesn't give sense related to the data I passed in in my csv file.

Comment: Data which you did not include with your post.

Comment: Apologies for that, but others already understood my problem and answered. I was unable to draw that graph because my professor worked with that data and the output of his graph was different than me. 
I knew I was doing something wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to sort your data **before** you write your x-axis data (price_date).

To get the desired result replace

```
price_date = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'])
data.sort_values('Date', inplace=True)    
price_close = data['Close']
```

with

```
data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'])
data.sort_values('Date', inplace=True) 
price_date = data['Date']
price_close = data['Close']
```

Comment: Have you thought about the meaning of `inplace=True`?

Comment: Thank you, it works fine now. it is exactly how my professor worked with this data and output this graph.

Answer (score 1):

You use `price_date = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'])` for the x-axis and after that you sort `data['Date']`. I guess this could be your problem (without actually knowing what your data looks like). Try:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

plt.style.use('seaborn')    
data = pd.read_csv('C:/py/matplotlib/08-TimeSeries/data.csv')

data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date']) # Just change the column itself to datetime
data.sort_values('Date', inplace=True)    
price_close = data['Close'] # This is not actually necessary. You can just use date['Close']  in the plot_date below

plt.plot_date(data['Date'], data['Close'], linestyle='solid')    
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```